Runtime error webpack-dev-server, solidity, openzeppelin
I'm working on a project using Truffle, solidity and openzeppelin. For web, I'm using the webpack-dev-server.
With Truffle, everything works, it compiles and migrates. Then I start the frontend with webpack-dev-server, but when I try to use the frontend to create an object, I get an error:
Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'methods')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'methods')
    at Object.createStar (webpack://app/./src/index.js?:38:38)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (http://localhost:8080/:21:68)

Here it is the code for index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>StarNotary DApp</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    input {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <h1>StarNotary Token DAPP</h1>

  <hr>

  <br>
    <h1>Create a Star</h1>
    <br><label for="starName">Star Name:</label><input type="text" id="starName"></input>
    <br><label for="starId">Star ID:</label><input type="text" id="starId"></input>
    <br><br><button id="createStar" onclick="App.createStar()">Create Star</button>
    <br><br>
    <br>

    <span id="status"></span>

    <br>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

Here for index.js:
import Web3 from "web3";
import starNotaryArtifact from "../../build/contracts/StarNotary.json";

const App = {
  web3: null,
  account: null,
  meta: null,

  start: async function() {
    const { web3 } = this;

    try {
      // get contract instance
      const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
      const deployedNetwork = starNotaryArtifact.networks[networkId];
      this.meta = new web3.eth.Contract(
        starNotaryArtifact.abi,
        deployedNetwork.address,
      );

      // get accounts
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      this.account = accounts[0];
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Could not connect to contract or chain.");
    }
  },

  setStatus: function(message) {
    const status = document.getElementById("status");
    status.innerHTML = message;
  },

  createStar: async function() {
    const { createStar } = this.meta.methods;
    const name = document.getElementById("starName").value;
    const id = document.getElementById("starId").value;
    await createStar(name, id).send({from: this.account});
    App.setStatus("New Star Owner is " + this.account + ".");
  }

};

window.App = App;

window.addEventListener("load", async function() {
  if (window.ethereum) {
    // use MetaMask's provider
    App.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    await window.ethereum.enable(); // get permission to access accounts
  } else {
    console.warn("No web3 detected. Falling back to http://127.0.0.1:9545. You should remove this fallback when you deploy live",);
    // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
    App.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:9545"),);
  }

  App.start();
});

And here for the .sol file:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.24;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract StarNotary is ERC721 {

    constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_) ERC721 (name_, symbol_) {}

    struct Star {
        string name;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Star) public tokenIdToStarInfo;
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) public starsForSale;

    
    // Create Star using the Struct
    function createStar(string memory _name, uint256 _tokenId) public { // Passing the name and tokenId as a parameters
        Star memory newStar = Star(_name); // Star is an struct so we are creating a new Star
        tokenIdToStarInfo[_tokenId] = newStar; // Creating in memory the Star -> tokenId mapping
        _mint(msg.sender, _tokenId); // _mint assign the the star with _tokenId to the sender address (ownership)
    }

    // Putting an Star for sale (Adding the star tokenid into the mapping starsForSale, first verify that the sender is the owner)
    function putStarUpForSale(uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _price) public {
        require(ownerOf(_tokenId) == msg.sender, "You can't sale the Star you don't owned");
        starsForSale[_tokenId] = _price;
    }


    // Function that allows you to convert an address into a payable address
    function _make_payable(address x) internal pure returns (address payable) {
        return payable(x);
    }

    function buyStar(uint256 _tokenId) public  payable {
        require(starsForSale[_tokenId] > 0, "The Star should be up for sale");
        uint256 starCost = starsForSale[_tokenId];
        address ownerAddress = ownerOf(_tokenId);
        require(msg.value > starCost, "You need to have enough Ether");
        transferFrom(ownerAddress, msg.sender, _tokenId); // We can't use _addTokenTo or_removeTokenFrom functions, now we have to use _transferFrom
        address payable ownerAddressPayable = _make_payable(ownerAddress); // We need to make this conversion to be able to use transfer() function to transfer ethers
        ownerAddressPayable.transfer(starCost);
        if(msg.value > starCost) {
            payable(msg.sender).transfer(msg.value - starCost);
        }
    }

}

Best regards

Make sure that your local node is running at http://127.0.0.1:9545. Otherwise, you need to replace this url with the exact RPC url of your local node.

Thanks for the comment. That's actually what was happening, issues with truffle and metamask.

Are you running a local ganache node?
